# How to achieve this button, but using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, icons

[image: Download Button]
[image: Download Button]

How can I create these two buttons in CSS and HTML? I know I can easily use the images as a background, but I want to be able to change the icon and the text in the button (instead of a down-arrow, make it a play or pause icon) when the button is clicked (which I can easily do with a "click" event listener). I was wondering if you could get these buttons [with play or pause icons instead of a download button and without the iLivid logo/text].

What do I have so far? Well, I am considering using an `<a>` for the button itself, an `<i class="[something]"></i>` inside of it for the icon, and a `<span>` to change the text. Changing the icon and text should be fairly straightforward, so I guess I could accomplish that by changing the class of the `<i>` element and using something like `$().text("Download");` to change the text.

These buttons were part of advertisements.

Comment: you can easily make that using class. The background using gradient and just make <img> inside a for the icon.

Comment: Go to the site with those buttons. Right mouse click on the button. Select Inspect Element from the context menu. In the Developer toolbar that opens up you will see the html structure used and in another panel the CSS used.

Comment: @jeff These buttons were images on an advertisement, not web elements.